# How to get the "path" in React... "location" not found

Tags: reactjs

Sorry! someone knows how to access the "context" parameters to extract the "path",
try to do it in the following way without success:
[image: React_Components]

```
    componentDid() {
      console.log("entre")
      const item = document.querySelector(
        this.props.location.state
      );
      if (item) {
        console.log(item);
      }
    }
```

imports:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link, BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Archive:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link, BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'; // prueba
import '../css/LobbyStyles.css'
import '../css/styleSearch.css'

const liStyle = {
    paddingLeft: '45px', 
    listStyleType: "none", 
};

export default class LobbyPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            listPlayers: [],
        };
    }

    componentDid() {
        console.log("entre")
        const item = document.querySelector(
            this.props.location.state
        );
        if (item) {
            console.log(item);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 className="h1TittleLobby">Lobby</h1>
                <Link to={`/game/`}>
                    <button className="buttonFound bttmodal bttLobby">Iniciar Partida</button>
                </Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When I try things like:
const location = useLocation();
console.log(location.pathname);
I get an error.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a route like this /Lobby/:lobbyID

this.props.location.pathname will return you /Lobby/1

this.props.match.params["lobbyID"] will return you 1

Also change

```
 componentDid()
```

to `componentDidMount()`